# What does "do not will have to" mean

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

How to interpret the phrase 'do not will have to'?

For example:

- Under the new system, although hospitality venues will be allowed to stay open until 11pm – with last orders at 10pm – only those that serve substantial meals can operate. It means pubs and bars that **do not will have to** close.

---

I understand that 'do not will' means 'do not want', for example: *If you do not will it, It remains a dream.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually two phrases.  The "do not" is part of the relative clause describing pubs and pars. The "will have to close" is the main verb.

> It means pubs and bars that do not [serve substantial meals,] will have to close.

(actually the main verb is is "means", but "pubs will have to close" is also a finite clause with "will have to close" as the finite verb.)